# How to create a parameter on a node with the name of the parameter being a value from the file being imported with Cypher/ APOC?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am new to neo4j and am trying to import some json formatted data.
I got the first steps of reading all json files and turning some data into nodes and edges. How to create a parameter of a node on the fly, I could not figure out.
`SET j[issn.type] = issn.value` should create a new parameter on j with the name of the value found in the json data and give it the value `issn.value`. The latter should be fine, but `j[issn.type]` does not seem to work.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

**Full Query**

```
call apoc.load.directory("*.json") yield value as files unwind files as file 
CALL apoc.load.json(file) YIELD value as object 
UNWIND object.items AS entry 
MERGE (p:Publisher {name: entry.publisher}) 
MERGE (j:Journal {name: entry.`container-title`}) 
ON CREATE SET j.created = timestamp()
FOREACH (issn IN entry.`issn-type` | 
  SET j[issn.type] = issn.value
)
MERGE (p)-[r:publishes]->(j) 
ON CREATE SET r.created = timestamp()
RETURN p
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `SET j[issn.type] = issn.value` to set the properties in Cypher, is not yet supported. To achieve this use `apoc.create.setProperty` function, something like this:

```
call apoc.load.directory("*.json") yield value as files 
unwind files as file 
CALL apoc.load.json(file) YIELD value as object 
UNWIND object.items AS entry 
MERGE (p:Publisher {name: entry.publisher}) 
MERGE (j:Journal {name: entry.`container-title`}) 
ON CREATE SET j.created = timestamp()
WITH p, j, entry
UNWIND entry.`issn-type` AS issn 
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(j, issn.type, issn.value)
YIELD node
MERGE (p)-[r:publishes]->(node) 
ON CREATE SET r.created = timestamp()
RETURN p
```

Here's the documentation [link](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.setProperty/#usage-apoc.create.setProperty). I am assuming in the query that `entry.issn_type` is some sort of list, that's why I am unwinding it, because we can't call `apoc` functions from within a `FOREACH` loop.

Comment: It doesn't seems to be OK to use apoc... as such: Invalid use of CALL inside FOREACH (line 9, column 2 (offset: 331))
" CALL apoc.create.setProperty(j, issn.type, issn.value)"

Comment: the new version works